# How to break a loop when "enter" is pressed in C++ while taking input in an integer array

Tags: c++

I have this loop, where `arr` is an integer array.

```
for(int i=0; i<=counter;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
```

I'm giving input like this

```
2 4 6 7
```

I want when enter is pressed after 7, just break this loop.

---

I think it can be done with something like

```
if(cin.get()=="\n")
```

But I can't understand how to implement it here in this code.

Comment: Apart from the I/O concern, you are aware that your loop ASSUMES `arr` has at least `counter+1` elements and will have undefined behaviour if  `arr` has only `counter` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to exit your for loop when you press the Enter Key. You would need to check the given input before putting it in your array.

And if it is equal to `'\n'`, leave the for loop with `break`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
    // Check if user pressed the Enter Key
    if(std::cin.peek() == '\n') {
        // Leave the for loop
        break;
    }
    std::cin >> arr[i];
}
```

To ensure that the input doesn't get cleared from `cin.get()` we can instead use [`cin.peek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/).

Comment: cin.get() removes input from cin. You might want to use peek instead. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/